# How to Convert PHP Associative array to json Array

Tags: php, json

I want to convert an associative array in PHP into a a json array but the result is quite different from what i want

**PHP Code**

```php
$output = array(
            "code": "UEX200",
            'email' => "username@gmail.com",
            'username' => "username,
            'type'         => "user",
            'account_manager' => "manager",
             status'       => "active
        );
```

**i want it to be in this format**

```
{
    "code": "UEX200",
    "details": [{
        "email": "username@gmail.com",
        "username": "username",
        "type": "user",
        "account_manager": "manager",
        "status": "active"
    }]
}
```

**But it outputs in this format**

```
{
    "code": "UEX200",
    "details": {
        "email": "username@gmail.com",
        "username": "username",
        "type": "user",
        "account_manager": "manager",
        "status": "active"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your array needs to look like this: `$array = [ "code" => "YOURCODE", "details" => [ [user_details_in_here], [.....], [......] ] ];`

Comment: still the same output

Comment: Darren comment should've worked. Can you post the code after the suggested changes?

Comment: @gustavo.lei It does haha - don't think the OP has tried it at all.... Example: https://tehplayground.com/ruKh3mmUefBLpxR4

Comment: @Darren yea, OP did try it when he was feeling really sleepy. thanks for the help though. it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$output = array(
        "code" => "UEX200",
      "details" => array(
        array(
        'email' => "username@gmail.com",
           'username' => "username,
           'type'         => "user",
           'account_manager' => "manager",
            status'       => "active
        )
     ); 
    );
```

try about code snap

```
{
"code": "UEX200",
"details": [{
    "email": "username@gmail.com",
    "username": "username",
    "type": "user",
    "account_manager": "manager",
    "status": "active"
}]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not correct for the result you want change your array like mention below.

```
$output = array(
        "code"=> "UEX200",
        "details"=>array(
        array('email' => "username@gmail.com",
        'username' => "username",
        'type'         => "user",
        'account_manager' => "manager",
         'status'       => "active")
    )
    );

print_r(json_encode($output,true));
?>
```